# Restricted Acces to the Attach file, ArcGIS Enterprise

Tags: arcgis-server

Can I restrict access to the attached files in my web applications in ArcGIS Enterprise (Portal) ? I want only some groups to have access to attached files.

Comment: put the attachments (item) in a new group and only invite the desired members to that group.

Comment: Yes but the attachments are added in ArcMap, so they will be accessible on all entities of web applications. We do not add the attachments on the portal.

Comment: thus your problem, you need to change your workflow for your desired results.

Comment: Ok I'll explain you, the attached files in question are Pdf files that are connected to each parcels of a geographical layer. So to bind the attachments to the parcels, we do it in ArcGIS for Desktop in edit mode.  So the attributes of each parcel are visible in all groups.

Comment: attachments are stored in a related table, (BLOB), share the item to the new group only... all users can see the parcels only desired users can see the attachments.  Not sure fi this will work for your case or not but worth a try

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: Thank you we solved the problem. we have published a layer on which attachments have been activated. So this layer is only accessible to some members of the Portal group